# Qual DTD utilizar no JSF com tags HTML5

Tags: html5, jsf-2.2

Geralmente, quando faço uma página JSF com XHTML, utilizo a DTD para XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Porém, se eu utilizar o namespace e colocar algumas tags HTML5 (passtrough elements/attributes), qual DTD devo usar?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
    <h:body>
        <input jsf:id="algumaID"/>
        <h:inputText pt:placeholder="algum texto"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

XHTML (pagina.xhtml)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

ou HTML5 (pagina.html)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O XHTML foi baseado no html 4. Portanto suas sintaxes não suportam coisas como required, inputs especiais como date, number ou outras facilidades do html5.
 Nós vindos do front-end, aguardamos ansiosamente a nova jsf com suporte para tal.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar qualquer um dos dois, eu pessoalmente uso a versão do **HTML5**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Mesmo sabendo que não importa, pois o JSF 2.2 sempre irá coloca-la, independente do que estiver no seu arquivo *xhtml*. Como você pode consultar [nesse artigo](http://blog.triadworks.com.br/suporte-a-html5-com-jsf-2-2#pass-through-elements)